# How to extract words between quotation and single words in textbox input using regex

Tags: c#, regex

**Problem:**

[Words to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Oqa.jpg)

So I have a textbox in which I input parts of title in quotation marks like "Lord of" and single words without quotation mark like Dance. I would like to extract all of them (Remove quotation marks and split them in some kind of list) so I can build SQL command which part is show below depending on some radiobutton choosing..

anyway

**So far I've tried:**

```
string pattern1 = "\"(.*?)\"";
MatchCollection col = Regex.Matches(textBox2.Text, @pattern1); //textbox2.Text is same as in picture


List<String> titles_to_query = new List<String> { };

            for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
            {
                titles_to_query .Add(col[i].Groups[1].Value.ToString()); 
            }
```

This would extract all of the titles in between the quotation marks

However how can I get Dance in my list (which is not surrounded by quotation marks)? Or what if someone types in  --> "Lord of" Dance "Friends

I would like to get Lord of and Dance in list, without Friends because it is missing one quotation mark...

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with SQL, so I'm removing that tag.

Comment: And I don't see any relation with the code you posted and the question... Post sample input, expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah true my bad, how? I want to extract the parts of titles and words that are being searched in textbox to a list...so I can do stuff with it..the part of code which I posted is my attempt, in which I extracted only stuff between quotation marks...but that wouldn't extract the word Dance for example which has no quotation marks surrounding it

Comment: You are asking *"How to extract words between quotation and single words"* but post some irrelated code. To get a better answer,  explain your problem in details. For example, (I have this text, I want to create this list from it and I tried this to do it)

Comment: edited..forgot to copy 2 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the better way of doing task.  I have done similar program at work and it does a real good job.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "\"Legend of Tarzan\" \"Lord of Dance\"";
            string pattern = "\"(?'phase'[^\"]+)\"";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            List<string> wheres = new List<string>();
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                wheres.Add(string.Format("title % '{0}'", match.Groups["phase"].Value));
            }

            string whereClause = string.Format("WHERE {0}", string.Join(" OR ", wheres));

            string SQL = string.Format(
                " SELECT movie_id, ts_headline, title, ts_rank, rank" +
                " FROM movies" +
                " {0}" +
                " ORDER BY rank DESC",
                whereClause);

        }
    }
}
```